# Why do we need to add : when defining a new column using .iloc function

Tags: python, pandas

When we make a new column in a dataset in `pandas`

`df["Max"] = df.iloc[:, 5:7].sum(axis=1)`

If we are only getting the columns from index 5 to index 7, why do we need to pass: as all the columns.

Comment: this is basic, and you would have the answer in the docs. the `:` means select all rows, while selecting columns in positions 5 and 6

Comment: The `:` means all rows in the selected columns, here column index 5 and 6.

Comment: ohhhhh. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.iloc()` is used purely for integer-location based indexing for selection by position [(read here for documentation).](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) The `:` means all rows in the selected columns, here column index 5 and 6 (`iloc` is not inclusive of the last index).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.iloc()` to take a slice out of the dataframe and apply an aggregate function across columns of the slice.

Consider an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0,1,2],"b":[2,3,4],"c":[4,5,6]})
df
```

would produce the following dataframe

```
   a  b  c
0  0  2  4
1  1  3  5
2  2  4  6
```

You are using `iloc` to avoid dealing with named columns, so that

```
df.iloc[:,1:3]
```

would look as follows

```
   b  c
0  2  4
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Now a slight modification of your code would get you a new column containing sums across columns

```
df.iloc[:,1:3].sum(axis=1)

0     6
1     8
2    10
```

Alternatively you could use function application:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:3].sum(), axis=1)

0     6
1     8
2    10
```

Thus you explicitly tell to apply `sum` across columns. However your syntax is more succinct and is preferable to explicit function application. The result is the same as one would expect.